# Create a connection with connection role between account and contact entity- programmatically

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to create a connection with connection role (Eg:test) between account entity and contact entity through c# code.

Can anyone tell me/share me code as to how to achieve this progamatically.

i got this reference from msdn..... but i am not able to do this.

```
 _serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();

                Connection newConnection = new Connection
                {
                    Record1Id = new EntityReference(Account.EntityLogicalName,
                        _accountId),
                    Record1RoleId = new EntityReference(ConnectionRole.EntityLogicalName,
                        _connectionRoleId),
                    Record2RoleId = new EntityReference(ConnectionRole.EntityLogicalName,
                        _connectionRoleId),
                    Record2Id = new EntityReference(Contact.EntityLogicalName,
                        _contactId)
                };
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried? See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Post a full code segment that we can review and attempt to execute? Also, what error message are you getting? Lastly, is this CRM 2011 or CRM 2016 - narrow down your tag to a specific version.

Comment: I was missing with the entity reference guid, now i am able to create a connection with the above code. Thanks